# Set alpha value to a particular figure on MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a matlab gui that contains two axes. I want to only change the alpha value of a plane that I am plotting in only one of my axes. For some reason the command alpha(0.5) is always getting defaulted to my first axes. Can anyone help me please?

Here is my code:

```
point1 = [2000,0,-1000]
point2 = [-2000,0,-1000]
point3 = [-2000,0,1000]
point4 = [2000,0,1000]

points = [point1' point2' point3' point4']
fill3(points(1,:),points(2,:),points(3,:),[1,0.4,0.5],'Parent',handles.axes2)
alpha(0.3,handles.axes2)//notworking
```

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe try `axes(handles.axes2); alpha(0.3)`

Comment: According to the doc you want `alpha(handles.axes2,0.3);`